# Server not Operational while accessing through SSL

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

My code works fine when not using ssl and connecting through port 389. But if I try to connect through 636 it shows server not operational although port is open.
My Code:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://52.xyz.xyz.151:636", admin,password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person))";
SearchResultCollection allUserDetails = searcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult user in allUserDetails)
{
        Console.WriteLine(user.Properties["name"][0].ToString());
}
```

The  above code works fine if I create the DirectoryEntry with port 389 as:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://52.xyz.xyz.151:389", admin,password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

The following variations also did not work

(using LDAPS instead of LDAP->didnot work)

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAPS://52.xyz.xyz.151:636", admin,password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

or
(using LDAPS instead of LDAP->didnot worknot writing port name)

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://52.xyz.xyz.151", admin,password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

Comment: Check whether the server has a (correct) certificate installed. Port 636 may be opened even if no certificate is installed.

Comment: Finally solved it

Comment: I have the same issue.  I am able to connect using other tools such as LDAP Admin.  I am also able to connect over TLS 1.2 using and LdapConnection.  DirectoryEntry is not working however.  Always the same error no matter the variation of trying to connect:  The server is not operational.  WireShark sniffs show the TLS 1.2 negotiation completing then the client sends a FIN as soon as the negotiation is complete.

Comment: @Raaj so what did you do to fix it?